# Spring security redirects to denied page even after successful login(From catalina.out)

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am wokring on a springg-mvc application and using Spring Security framework for authentication and authorization. I will be posting some code before, but before that, please know that I don't have a seperate table as Roles where one can set or retrieve roles. So whenever I login, it goes to denied.jsp. When I checked catalina.out, it says, hibernate after query could find one set of rows.

Security-context.xml (Part of it)

```
<security:http use-expressions="true" auto-config="false" access-denied-page="/403" disable-url-rewriting="true">
        <security:session-management>
            <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="5" />
        </security:session-management>
        <security:form-login login-page="/login" login-processing-url="/login.do" default-target-url="/users" always-use-default-target="true"
                             authentication-failure-url="/denied" username-parameter="username" password-parameter="password"/>
        <security:logout logout-url="/logout" logout-success-url="/login?out=1" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID" invalidate-session="true" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" requires-channel="any" access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url requires-channel="any" pattern="/login*" access="permitAll"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" requires-channel="any" access="hasRole('ROLE_USER')" />

    </security:http>

    <!-- queries to be run on data -->

    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider >
            <security:jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="dataSource" users-by-username-query="select username,password,true
                from registration where username=?" authorities-by-username-query="select u.username, 'ROLE_USER' from registration where u.username=?" />
          </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>
```

LoginService

```
//Imports ommited
@Transactional
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class LoginService implements UserDetailsService{

    @Autowired private UserDao userDao;
    @Autowired private Assembler assembler;

    @Override
    @Transactional
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
            UserDetails userDetails = null;
            User user = userDao.findByName(username);
            if(user == null) { throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Wrong username or password");}
        return assembler.buildUserFromUserEntity(user);
    }
}
```

Assembler :

```
@Service("assembler")
public class Assembler {
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    User buildUserFromUserEntity(com.WirTauschen.model.User userEntity){
        String username = userEntity.getUsername();
        String password = userEntity.getPassword();
        int id = userEntity.getId();
        boolean enabled = userEntity.isActive();
        boolean accountNonExpired = userEntity.isAccountNonExpired();
        boolean credentialsNonExpired = userEntity.isCredentialsNonExpired();
        boolean accountNonLocked = userEntity.isAccountNonLocked();

        Collection<GrantedAuthority> authorities = new ArrayList<GrantedAuthority>();
        authorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_USER"));
        User user1 = new User(username,password,enabled,accountNonExpired,credentialsNonExpired,accountNonLocked,authorities);
        return  user1;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use your implementation of `UserDetailsService`:

```xml
<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
  <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService"/>
</security:authentication-manager>
```

Comment: Hello Holmis83 : Thank you for the reply. Syntax forbids me from using only authentication provider outside realm of authentication-manager, and authentication-manager consists of code for using JDBC by <security:jdbc-user-service>. Should I still include that with another line of authentication provider. I hope there is no conflict.

Comment: @Orici It is allowed to have multiple authentication providers, but probably you only want one. So choose either `jdbc-user-service` *or* `user-service-ref`. Since you have made an implementation of `UserDetailsService`, I assumed you wanted the later.

Comment: Thanks man. THis really helped a lot. Plus 1 already given.. :-)